# Register the last user who made modifications to the document in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I need to indicate which user made the last modification of the document in MongoDB.

I have the following Categories model:

```
import { Schema, model } from "mongoose";

const CategorySchema = Schema (
  {
    name: {
        type: String,
        maxlength:50,
        unique: true,
        required: [true, 'El Nombre es obligatorio']
    },
    desc: {
        type: String,
        maxlength:50,
        required: [true, 'El Apellido es obligatorio']
    },
    img: {
        type: String
    },
    status: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: true,
        required: [true, 'El Estatus es obligatorio']
    },
    user:{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:'Users',
        required: [true, 'El Usuario es obligatorio']
    },
   createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
  }  
);
```

My idea is to get the _id of the user who is doing the update and insert it into another object in the model and also another object that gets the update date. Something like:

```
    lastModificationBy:{ 
        type: String,
        maxlength:50,
        required: true           
    },
    updatedAt:{ 
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now            
    }
```

However, I do not know if this is correct and functional. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, this schema should work, But you will have to send the user from the client side as a key:value, as you will be only able to get back the _id of the elements that you insert or modify. So you will have to pass another value to the schema from the local machine and that should do it. Also now MONGO-DB has a separate package for this. As I did face some issues with Mongoose last month, Try upgrading to the official mongoDB package https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb

Comment: @SARANSURYA thanks a lot!